# Boostrap video carousel height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am implementing this bootstrap video carousel in my code:

```
<div class="row">

        <h2>Videos</h2>
        <hr />

        <div class="carousel slide" id="videoCarousel" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#videoCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#videoCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#videoCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#videoCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SEBLt6Kd9EY?controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
                </div>

            <div class="item">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SEBLt6Kd9EY?controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://youtu.be/pVgtPovVSbY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SEBLt6Kd9EY?controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#videoCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#videoCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">c</span>
                </a>

            </div>            
        </div>
```

I use the same code for a image carousel and for that one I obviously use img instead of Iframe as tag for the elements to display. I just don't understand why in the case of the video carousel I get the videos displayed at a fixed height and if I change it via CSS the video is rendered  always with that same height but inside of a frame with empty space in it.

To make my self clearer I'd like to have the carousel display videos in a 800x600 size or similar as they are on youtube. I am not familiar with bootstrap or the use of carousels, so I guess I am missing something very basic...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i was just embedding code from youtube using the wrong settings. Predictably, noobish mistakes....!